# How to put text inside radio button?

Tags: css, radio-button, materialize

I am trying to put a letter inside a radio button (with Materialize framework) like the A and B in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFWjI.png).

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do that. But instead, you can make something similar using CSS:

```css
label {display: block; padding: 5px; position: relative; padding-left: 20px;}
label input {display: none;}
label span {border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 15px; height: 15px; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; line-height: 1; text-align: center; border-radius: 100%; font-size: 10pt; left: 0; top: 50%; margin-top: -7.5px;}
input:checked + span {background: #ccf; border-color: #ccf;}
```

```html
<h3>Select One</h3>
<label><input type="radio" name="select" /><span>a</span> Item 1</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="select" /><span>b</span> Item 2</label>
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

Answer (score 6):

Here is the customize radio button.

*see the comments given in css.*

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 2px solid #1FBED6;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-appearance: none; /*to disable the default appearance of radio button*/
  -moz-appearance: none;
}

input[type="radio"]:focus { /*no need, if you don't disable default appearance*/
  outline: none; /*to remove the square border on focus*/
}

input[type="radio"]:checked { /*no need, if you don't disable default appearance*/
  background-color: #1FBED6;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked ~ span:first-of-type {
  color: white;
}

label span:first-of-type {
  position: relative;
  left: -27px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #1FBED6;
}

label span {
  position: relative;
  top: -12px;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="options"/>
  <span>A</span><span>Option A</span>
</label>
<br/>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="options"/>
  <span>B</span><span>Option B</span>
</label>
<br/>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="options"/>
  <span>C</span><span>Option C</span>
</label>
<br/>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="options"/>
  <span>D</span><span>Option D</span>
</label>
```