# How to add a placeholder to a radio button?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if there was a way to add a placeholder to a radio button. I tried to do it, code below, but it did not work. I want the first button to have the placeholder value "1", and the second to have the value "2" and so on. Is there a way to do that? I mean that the button, when the user looks at it, will have number "1" in it.

```
  function drawTable(daysInMonth) {
          var cellsToDraw = daysInMonth;
          var table = document.getElementById("table");
          table.innerHTML = "";
          for (r = 0; r < (daysInMonth / 7); r++) {
            var newRow = document.createElement("tr");
            table.appendChild(newRow);
            for (c = 0; c < 7 && cellsToDraw > 0; c++) {
              var newCell = document.createElement("input");
              newCell.setAttribute("type", "radio");
              newCell.setAttribute("name", "day");
              newCell.setAttribute("placeholder", 1)
              newRow.appendChild(newCell);
              newCell.innerHTML = //add the numbers here? 
              cellsToDraw--;
            }
          }
        }
```

CSS:

```
input[type=radio] {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 0.5em;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 95px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: -4px;
  margin-top: -8px;
}
```

All help is appriciated!

Comment: Where do you think the placeholder text should show on a radio button?

Comment: @Dummy I added my css. Well I wanted it to be shown inside of the button, since I have made the button bigger with CSS

Answer (score 1):

Radio buttons don't support placeholders, and there wouldn't be any space to render one in anyway.

It sounds like you are confusing placeholders with labels (see [this article](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)).

Use a LABEL element instead.

---

Aside: INPUT elements are not allowed to be children of TR elements. Only TD and TH elements may be children of a TR.

---

```js
function drawTable(daysInMonth) {
  var cellsToDraw = daysInMonth;
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  document.body.appendChild(table);
  for (r = 0; r < (daysInMonth / 7); r++) {
    var newRow = document.createElement("tr");
    table.appendChild(newRow);
    for (c = 0; c < 7 && cellsToDraw > 0; c++) {
      var newCell = document.createElement("td");
      var input = document.createElement("input");
      var label = document.createElement("label");
      input.setAttribute("type", "radio");
      input.setAttribute("name", "day");
      label.appendChild(input);
      label.appendChild(document.createTextNode("1"));
      newCell.appendChild(label);
      newRow.appendChild(newCell);
      cellsToDraw--;
    }
  }
}

drawTable(30);
```

Comment: Well I have made my buttons bigger with css, so that is why I want the text inside of the button. So there is no possible way of doing that?

Comment: That's a matter of styling the label appropriately, not using something that is designed for an entirely different purpose (on a different element).

Comment: So I added my css, is there a way to add the lable 1 inside of the button now?

Answer (score 0):

instead of innerHTML you can set value

```
newCell.value = c
```

Comment: Thanks! but Im cannot change the value of the button, using it in another function. Thats why I just want the number to be shown in the button

Comment: just append another text element near radio

Comment: no sure what you mean

Comment: i meant if you want to show what value that radio button holds by a text element next to radio button. but if you want to show value inside the radio button you would have to create a span element with design of radio

Comment: how would I do that since my function creats the buttons?

Comment: since you have big button's there is an another way

Comment: What way would that be?

Comment: jquery will be easier to do that  , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45259139/how-to-put-text-inside-radio-button

Comment: So I saw that question, but where should I add the label and the span? They put it outside of the input, but I have my input inside of the function. Im not using any HTML

Comment: first write label then add input inside label with js